# IIS not showing connections and no default website?

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7, iis-express

[image: inetmgr]

I have windows 7 32-bit and tried to install IIS Express but when I am opening inetmgr, it shows like in image, can you please guide me how I can setup IIS or fix this issue

Comment: Are you trying it with admin user?

Comment: You cannot use IIS Manager to manage IIS Express. Please use a tool such as Jexus Manager, http://JexusManager.com

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a web server by using IIS Manager

1. Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see [Open IIS Manager (IIS 8)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635847(v=ws.11).aspx).
2. In the **Connections** pane, expand **Create New Connection** in the toolbar.
3. Click **Connect to a Server** to open the **Connect to Server** Wizard.
4. On the **Specify Server Connection Details** page, in the **Server name** box, type the name of the server to which you want to connect. If you must specify a port number over which to connect, type the port number with a colon after the server name. For example, type **WESTSRV01:8080**. To connect to the local computer, type **localhost** instead of the server name.
5. Click **Next**. On the **Provide Credentials** page type a user name and password in the **User name** and **Password** boxes.
6. Click **Next**.
7. On the **Specify a Connection Name** page, in the **Connection Name** box, type a friendly name for your connection and then click **Finish**. This friendly name appears in the tree after the connection is made.

Comment: In the Connections pane, its all disabled, I am not able to click and create :(

Comment: And when you click on File?

Comment: save connections (as disabled) and exit